# Render foreign key __str__ method in a template django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

```
class A(models.Model):
   field1 = models.CharField(max_length=10)   
   field2 = models.IntegerField(default=0)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.field1 + str(self.field2)

class B(models.Model):
  a = models.ForeignKey(A)
  ...
```

Now in a template I want to render the "a" attribute of an instance of model B by using:
`{{ binstance.a }}` but this seems to either render empty string or nothing at all.

How do I render the **str** methdod of a foreign key within the template?

Comment: do you want to print field1 and field2 using "a" attribute ?

Comment: I want to be able to print string representation of foreign key attribute in an easy manner. I don't want to put {{ binstance.a.field1 }} {{ binstance.a.field2 }} in the template, I'd rather have a compact representation of model A instance accessible by rendering the instance of A using {{ ainstance }} in the template

Comment: I am not sure, but I don't think django provide this way in template. Although you can think of reverse foreign key n template

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually it's default django behaviour. Check do you pass `B` instance with template context and use correct variable name in your template.

Comment: Yes! I was passing B.objects.all().values() to the template instead of B.objects.all(). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe would I choose a different approach and create a [template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags)

```
@register.filter(name='fullname')
def fullname(pk):
    b = B.objects.get(pk=pk)
    field1 = b.a.first_name
    field2 = b.a.last_name
    return "{} {}".format(field1, field2)
```

Then you can use `{{binstance.pk|fullname}}`